# How to evaluate the contour integral $\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z e^z }{\tan^2 z}dz$ over the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Let $C(0, 1)$ be the unit circle centered at the origin with radius $1$. Then I need to evaluate the following complex contour integral: $$ \int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z e^z }{\tan^2 z}dz$$ I know the function $f(z) = \frac{z e^z}{\tan^2 z}$ has singularities at $z = n\pi$ with $n = 0, 1, \ldots $ But only only the first singularity lies inside the contour. So should I compute the residue $\text{Res}(f(z), z=0)$? Would this be a pole of order 2?

Comment: "Yes" and "no".

Comment: How do I compute the residue then? I cannot use the formula $g(z_0) / h'(z_0)$, since in this case $g(z_0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: 
$$
\frac{z e^z}{\tan^2 z} = \frac{z e^z}{\sin^2 z}\cos^2 z =\\
 \frac{z(1+z+z^2/2+\dots)}{(z - z^3/6+\dots)^2}(1-z^2/2+\dots)^2=\frac{1}{z}+\dots.
$$
From above $\text{Res}(f(z), z=0) = 1$.

Comment: How did you deduce that this can be written as $1 / z + \ldots $ ? Did you plug in $z = 0$ ?

Comment: @Kamil No, I just multiply all the staff in mind. Also note that $\frac{1}{(z - z^3/6+\dots)^2} = \frac{1}{z^2}(1+z^2/3+\dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is a pole of order $1$. So by residual theorem
$$
\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z e^z}{\tan^2 z}dz=2\pi iRes(f(z),0)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^2 e^z}{\tan^2 z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^2 e^z \cos^2 z}{\sin^2 z}=1
$$
Note that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^2 }{\sin^2 z}=1
$$

Comment: Where has $2\pi i$ gone in the answer?

Comment: $2πi$ is outside $C(0,1)$